# What expression is missing in this sql command?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, inner-join, oracle-apex

I put in this SQL command and it tells me I am missing an expression. What is it?

```
SELECT Warehouse_Number, DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT Order_Number) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Part, Order_Line
WHERE Part.Part_Number=Order_Line.Part_Number
GROUP BY Warehouse_Number;
```

Comment: What inspred you to use DISTINCT? BTW: there are JOINs (since 1992)

Comment: I need to find how many orders came from each warehouse.

Comment: You need to find the syntax and semantics of SQL first.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select p.warehouse_number, count(distinct ol.order_number) as numberoforders
from part p
inner join order_line ol on ol.part_number = p.part_number
group by p.warehouse_number;
```

That is:

- use `distinct` only once, within aggregate function `count()`; the other way to use that keyword is to put it directly after `select` (as in `select distinct ...`), but this does not make sense for an aggregation query to start with
- use standard joins! Implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause and join conditions in the `where` clause) are archaic syntax, that should not be used in new code
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- in a multi-table query, all columns should be qualified with the (alias of the) table they belong to - I assumed that `warehouse_number` comes from `part`

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct` modifier can only appear at the beginning of the select list or inside an aggregate function, not before a non-first select element.

Since you're using a `group by` clause you don't need it anyway - just drop it, and you should be OK:

```
SELECT Warehouse_Number, COUNT(DISTINCT Order_Number) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Part, Order_Line
WHERE Part.Part_Number=Order_Line.Part_Number
GROUP BY Warehouse_Number;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant

```
SELECT Warehouse_Number, 
COUNT(DISTINCT Order_Number) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Part as P
join Order_Line as OL  --Possible inner join
on P.<some variable> = OL.<some variable> --Hopefully a key between variables
WHERE Part.Part_Number=Order_Line.Part_Number
GROUP BY Warehouse_Number;
```

Comment: Using `AS` between the table identifier and its alias is invalid syntax in Oracle.